# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

while running SpringMVC program through eclipse showing below error

> 'Starting Tomcat v8.0 at localhost' has encountered a problem. Server
>   Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

using eclipse luna configured with tomcat 8.0

below is the relevant stacktrace of the error

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVCValidation    sApp7SFC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you ccn see in the root exception: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log`

You miss the commons-logging.jar in your classpath.

Comment: oh! thank you so much @jens I forgot to add that jar. i am thinking why it is showing tomcat error...

Answer (score 2):

In my non-Spring web app I had a similar problem. I solved it by checking the `.classpath` file and corrected this entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

The  attribute `org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency` had been missing.

Comment: Had the same problem (Tomcat7, Spring-based webapp built with Java11)... maybe because this `.classpath` has been generated by call to `mvn eclipse:eclipse`; I should deffo continue investigating this...